# Rust is giving "has overflowed its stack" error in println in test

Tags: rust

Can anyone explain why this code is giving error in a simple println statement?

```
fn set() -> String {
    String::from("Foo")
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn set() {
        println!("{:?}", set());
        assert!(true)
    }
}
```

is giving following error

```
thread 'tests::set' has overflowed its stack
fatal runtime error: stack overflow
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your test function is called `set`, `println!("{:?}", set())` causes infinite recursion.  Symbols declared in the local module supersede those imported with `use`.

Instead, use `println!("{:?}", super::set())` to indicate that you want to invoke the `set` function in the parent module.

Alternatively, you could call your test function something other than `set`, or import `set` from the parent scope under a different name by doing e.g. `use super::set as real_set`, and then invoking `real_set()` instead of `set()`.